# I want to refresh a view in siebel on a button click

Tags: siebel, escript

I am using siebel v 8.0.

I would like to refresh the view when button in an applet is clicked.

When the button is clicked, I need some code in browser script that can refresh the view.

I have tried

```
1. this.BusComp().InvokeMethod("RefreshRecord");
2. this.BusComp().InvokeMethod("RefreshBusComp");
3. theApplication().InvokeMethod("RefreshBusComp"); 
4. theApplication().GetService("FINS Teller UI Navigation").InvokeMethod ("RefreshCurrentApplet", theApplication(). NewPropertySet(), theApplication().NewPropertySet());
```

But none of them worked. But i need entire view to be refreshed instead of current applet.Please help.
.

Answer (score 2):

While using BS:FINS Teller UI Navigation, try passing the parameter "Refresh All" as true.

```
var svcUI = TheApplication().GetService("FINS Teller UI Navigation");
var psIn = TheApplication().NewPropertySet();
var psOut = TheApplication().NewPropertySet();
psIn.SetProperty("Refresh All","Y");
svcUI.InvokeMethod("RefreshCurrentApplet",psIn,psOut);
```

If that still does not work for you, you can try javascript to refresh the view, assuming your App is in high interactivity. Use window.location.reload() in javascript to refresh the entire view.

Comment: Thanks Ranjith. FINS Teller UI Navigation worked in server script. But, in browser script this didn't work.

I am using the same code with theApplication() instead of TheApplication().

Comment: I'm 3 years late, but for the benefit of future readers: in order to invoke a business service from browser scripts, you have to register the BS first, either [in the CFG file (Siebel 7.8 and earlier)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B31104_02/books/OIRef/OIRefInterfaceRef52.html#wp1009248) or [in Siebel Tools (Siebel 8.0+)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B40099_02/books/OIRef/OIRefInterfaceRef51.html#wp1009248)

Answer (score 1):

Intercept the button click event on Browser Side Script on Applet and Invoke customized Business Service from Browser Side Script. On the Server Side Script of Business Service use

```
TheApplication().GoToView("Name Of View to Refresh");
```

Pass 'View Name' and other parameter from Browser to Server side to maintain context this will make it generic and reusable. At last you will have refreshed View.